C# OIDC client library - how to provide our own logger
I am investigating an OIDC specific issue from my desktop based application where I am using IdentityModel.OidcClient library. Overall it works well but if any OIDC authority specific server is down it crashes the application without any details about exception.
To investigate that I want to provide my logger to the oidcclient library. I see an option of adding it through "_oidcClient.Options.LoggerFactory.AddProvider()"
I have Log4Net setup, I assume it should work but somehow I am not getting proper option to pass ILoggerProvider.
In below sample I see SeriLog has been added but that seems an old library and now it looks like support all the log providers.
https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel.OidcClient/blob/main/clients/ConsoleClientWithBrowser/Program.cs
Can someone suggest how can I do that or share some sample of it ?
Thanks,

LoggerFactory - is a Microsoft class, AddSerilog - serilog library extension, which adds mentioned provider (wrapper around serilog). Look inside, do the same with your  logger. Write 1-2 minute wrapper around Log4Net if not found.
